# Cross reference mailing lists in excel/access

Tags: excel

I have two separate mailing lists. One is in excel and the other is in access. How can I cross reference these two lists to omit duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

You can link the Excel worksheet as a table in Access and use a Union query to create a single list, without updating or changing either of the existing lists:

```
SELECT SName, Address FROM AccessTable
UNION
SELECT SName, Address FROM ExcelTable
```

Union will avoid duplicates, UNION ALL creates a list that includes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

In Access, make the email address field unique (Indexed, No duplicates).
Then Append your XL data to it. The duplicates will be ignored, and you will end up with a list without dupes.